# Is there any way to save PHP sessions in RAM?

Tags: php, windows, security, nginx

I have php with nginx. I want to make PHP save it's sessions on RAM for security reasons. Is there any way doing it?

If it's impossible, is there is any advice to make php sessions unrecoverable from hard disk after the server is shutdown?

After a lot of searching I've found the `Shared memory` module of php, which can be used like persistent memory cache over sessions. is it shared with other applications too?, and how secure is it?

Comment: First thought: create a RAM disk and use it in `session_save_path`.

Comment: @zaak Basically a good idea but it will not scale.

Comment: what 'security' do you actually think your gaining ? - if your physical file system is not secure -you have real issues

Comment: i just want security from retiaining it from hdd after delete :) .

Comment: @zaak ram disk is not that easy to make on windows :(

Comment: still makes no sens 'security' wise

Comment: @MajedDH In professional environments hard disks will get shredded after usage. That's part of the policy.

Comment: you have MUCH bigger issues if *anyone*  has access to the server hdd

Comment: can you explain @Dagon ? . i want to store some kind of encryption key in sessions  to persist the same variable over requests .

Comment: we are all lost as to what you are 'securing' and from what.

Comment: well. can shred session files in php ? . i've searched alot for shredding using php on windows . but i couldn't find any thing.

Comment: Use memcached or mysql with memory storage engine. That's it. No need to tinker something.

Comment: i can't have mysql. can sqlite3 do it ? @hek2mgl

Comment: How can you expect help if you don't listen? I told **no need to tinker something** and you start to look at shm. Nothing more to say for me

Comment: sorry to make you mad @hek2mgl . but how can i store the key securely  in a client-server app where a client and server are on the same machine? i'm just afraid of stealing the machine

Comment: The client needs to run as a different user. This is possible in Windows too. Then make sure that the client has a limited system access and is not able to access the secret data. that's it.

Comment: @hek2mgl i would makr it as answer if you put it down :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`memcached`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) to store session data in RAM. If you are already using a database you might simply use a memory storage engine. However, I don't get what security reasons you have in mind. If you have concerns that somebody is able to access your session data then make sure that he is not able to do so. Regardless where they are stored as otherwise the security is completely broken.

**Update**

You told that the client and the server are running on the same physical machine. I can imagine of a kiosk application.

As a general advice the client needs to run as a different user. This is possible in Windows too. Then make sure that the client has a limited system access and is not able to access the secret data. that's it.

You might also consider to separate server and client using virtual machines.

Comment: any body can access memcached  (ignoring that there is firewall)

Comment: *anybody*? how is this hosted, on a public pc in the local  library ?

Comment: I don't get the concerns actually. Can you elaborate?

Comment: my project is a local server with local browser (on the same PC)

Comment: And how should anybody be able to access the data?

Comment: i'm willing to store the key in the session and if it's on the hdd it would be easier to recover it than if it's on ram